# What Java code will force javac 1.6 to use the 'swap' and 'nop' opcodes?

Tags: java, jvm, javac, bytecode, opcode

I'm working on an amateur JVM implementation, and I'm trying to make sure I have test coverage for all of the opcodes in the spec. I've gotten it down to the last few, but `nop` and `swap` have been eluding me. For example, here's a simple function that might use `swap`:

```
static int do_swap() {
  int a = 56;
  int b = 32;
  return b%a;
}
```

But the bytecode produced by `javac 1.6` avoids swapping in lieu of local storage:

```
static int do_swap();
  Code:
   0:   bipush  56
   2:   istore_0
   3:   bipush  32
   5:   istore_1
   6:   iload_1
   7:   iload_0
   8:   irem
   9:   ireturn
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

None.  The Java Language Specification does not provide such guarantees.  You can just write your own Java bytecode using [Jasmin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jasmin_%28Java_assembler%29) (a bytecode assembler).

Comment: I think the Krakatau assembler would be more useful for generating JVM test cases, since it supports more obscure features of the classfile format that Jasmin doesn't. (Disclosure I wrote it). But for something simple like this, Jasmin is good enough.