# Use cases of jvm dup instruction

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

Java bytecode instruction set provides [various forms of dup instruction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.dup_x1). I'm having trouble understanding how these instructions and the `swap` instruction might be useful.
What java code would produce bytecode with these instructions when compiled?

Comment: I don’t think that this question is too broad. There are some simple practical examples, everyday Java code contains, e.g. [object instantiation typically uses `dup`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53223409/2711488). Further, `intArray[expression]++` gets compiled to `…, dup2, iaload, iconst_1, iadd, iastore`. As discussed [in this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9722421/2711488), `javac` does never use `swap` or `nop` (in the current implementation).

Comment: @Holger What about `x` variants of `dup`, i.e. `dup_x1`, `dup2_x1` etc. I'm writing an instrumentation tool for java language and it would make life hell of a lot easier if I could just ignore these instructions.

Comment: Just because `javac` does not use a particular instruction, you can not assume that no compiler uses it. E.g. there are other Java compilers, like ECJ, but there can be class files created by other programming languages or being already the result of an instrumentation tool. And things can change. Before Java 8, Java code did not use `invokedynamic`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variants of `dup` can appear in ordinary Java code.

E.g. as elaborated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53223409/2711488), object instantiation typically uses `dup`, as `new Object()` gets compiled to

```
new #n              // n referencing Class java.lang.Object in the pool
dup
invokespecial #m    // m referencing Method java.lang.Object.<init>()V
```

Further, `intArray[expression]++` gets compiled to

```
… (code pushing the results of intArray and expression)
dup2
iaload
iconst_1
iadd
iastore
```

and, a bit fancier

```
public static long example3(Long[] array, int i, long l) {
    return array[i]=l;
}
```

compiles to

```
   0: aload_0
   1: iload_1
   2: lload_2
   3: invokestatic  #3  // Method java/lang/Long.valueOf:(J)Ljava/lang/Long;
   6: dup_x2
   7: aastore
   8: invokevirtual #4  // Method java/lang/Long.longValue:()J
  11: lreturn
```

<sup>Changing the array type to `long[]` produces an example of `dup2_x2`</sup>

As discussed in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9722421/2711488), `javac` does never use `swap` or `nop` (in the current implementation). But just because `javac` does not use a particular instruction, you can not assume that no compiler uses it.

E.g. there are other Java compilers, like `ECJ`, but there can be class files created by other programming languages or being already the result of an instrumentation tool, which becomes relevant when you want to instrument code at runtime. And future versions of `javac` also can use instructions they didn’t use before, just like before Java 8, Java code did not use `invokedynamic`.

[This discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25746587/2711488) points to a scenario, where `swap` would be appropriate. When using try-with-resource, there will be generated code, handling an exception caught while there is already a caught exception. Current `javac` compiles it (basically) to

```
astore        n
aload         o
aload         n
invokevirtual #x // Method java/lang/Throwable.addSuppressed:(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
```

where `o` is the old variable holding the already caught exception and `n` will be an entirely new variable, which would not be needed when compiling this to

```
aload         o
swap
invokevirtual #x // Method java/lang/Throwable.addSuppressed:(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
```

instead. So it’s not like these instruction were never-needed exotic constructs. It’s just an implementation detail when a particular code generator doesn’t use them.

Speaking of Instrumentation, it’s also important to keep in mind that a `ClassFileTransformer` is not guaranteed to receive exactly the same bytecode as produced by the compiler. It might be an equivalent byte code.

So the bottom line is, if you want to implement a `ClassFileTransformer`, you should be prepared to handle every legal byte code.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know when javac uses it, but when we generate code we use DUP and SWAP a lot. For example if you're doing the equivalent of

```
x.setCharm(y);
x.setSpin(z);
```

then you would load x and immediately DUP it, because invoking the first method will take it off the stack and you want to use it twice.

SWAP comes in handy when you're doing something like

```
y = x.getCharm();
z.setCharm(y);
```

where the first instruction leaves y on top of stack, you then stack z, and SWAP, so you now have the right values on stack to invoke the second instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Another common use-case for `dup` is array initialisation.

Consider the code `int[] a = new int[] {1, 2, 3}`.

The [iastore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se14/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.iastore) instruction stores an integer into an array. It requires three values on the stack: a reference to the array, the index in that array and the value to store and, crucially, it pops all three values after it's called:

> The arrayref, index, and value are popped from the operand stack.
>   [Java Virtual Machine Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se14/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.iastore)

A naive way to translate the above example into byte code could look like this:

```
iconst_3
newarray       int
iconst_0               # array index
iconst_1               # value
iastore                # a[0] = 1
aload_1                # load array ref again
iconst_1
iconst_2
iastore                # a[1] = 2
aload_1                # load array ref yet again
iconst_2
iconst_3
iastore                # a[2] = 3
...
astore_1
```

Note, that the reference to the array gets reloaded for every `iastore` instruction.

This can be avoided using `dup`. Before pushing the index and the value to the stack, we duplicate the array reference on the stack which leaves the bottom entry there to be re-used for the next `iastore` instruction:

```
iconst_3
newarray       int
dup
iconst_0
iconst_1
iastore                # a[0] = 1
dup
iconst_1
iconst_2
iastore                # a[1] = 2
dup
iconst_2
iconst_3
iastore                # a[2] = 3
...
astore_1
```

Comment: I would assume that `dup` is a slightly "cheaper" JVM instruction than loading from a local variable. I tried to benchmark this (initialising an int array with 1.000 values 1.000.000 times) using both versions (`aload` vs. `dup`) but my results are inconclusive. The difference might be more in terms of best practices (avoiding re-loading something that's already available) rather than a true performance impact. I might be wrong, though.